# Android voice-recognition seems to be case sensitive

Tags: android, voice-recognition

I was implementing voice-recognition in my App. Everything is working in English language but e.g. in German there is the problem of case sensitivity.

For the command

```
    <string name="voice_shutdown">Abschalten</string>
```

the app recognizes "abschalten" in lower case only.

For the command

```
    <string name="voice_indicator_left">Blinker links</string>
```

the app recognizes "Blinker links" correct (probably because "Blinker" is a noun and nouns are written uppercase in German).

In fact I can try and error all commands and write them in that way the voice-recognition recognizes them, but I think, that is not a good solution.

Does anybody knows a workaround/ solution for this problem?